# Repeating in python pynput

Tags: python, pynput

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller import time

keyboard = Controller()

time.sleep(60)

# 1
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)

# 2
i = 0
while i < 4:
    keyboard.press(Key.tab)
    keyboard.release(Key.tab)
    i = i + 1;

# 3
i= 0
while i < 3:
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    i = i + 1;

# 4
i = 0
while i < 4:
    with keyboard.pressed(Key.shift):
        keyboard.press(Key.tab)
        keyboard.release(Key.tab)
        i = i + 1;
```

---

I want the above code to loop indefinitely, but it does not work. What's wrong?

Could you give me some advice? About GUI and EXE filing

Comment: What are you expecting to loop forever?

Comment: So put it in an endless loop?

Comment: `while True ...` _code you want to run forever_

Comment: yeah, I want just endless loop.

Comment: Where should I put it? `while True:`

Comment: I am not positive what segment of code you want to run indefinitely be in the `for` loop

Comment: I posted in an answer

Comment: I really cannot see what you're having problems with. You obviously know how to create a `while` loop, so just do that again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this you loop indefinitely because `True` well... always evaluate to true so the loop will never break unless you explicitly tell it to.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller 
import time

keyboard = Controller()

while True:
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    for i in range(0, 4):
        keyboard.press(Key.tab)
        keyboard.release(Key.tab)
    for i in range(0, 3):
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
   ...

   time.sleep(60)
```

It's also better practice to replace the `while` statements with `for` loops. That's what is typical practice when you intend to execute a block of code a determinate number of times i.e. 4 times as opposed to when you want to execute a block of code an indeterminate amount of time you use a `while` loop

Comment: I want "first enter" -> tab*4 -> enter*3 -> (shift+tab)*4. and return "first enter". I tried while True: but the program did not respond.

Comment: @무공해 ok I think your code needs a slight rewrite then I'll do in an example of what the first bits should look like..

Comment: Everything I wanted was redone every minute. I am trying to change the location of while True, but I have tried various things because of various errors.

Comment: @무공해 then put the `time.sleep(60)` in the while loop.

Comment: `from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller()

while True:
    time.sleep(20)
    #1
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    #2
    for i in range(0, 4):
        keyboard.press(Key.tab)
        keyboard.release(Key.tab)
    #3
    for i in range(0, 3):
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    #4
    for i in range(0, 4):
        with keyboard.pressed(Key.shift):
            keyboard.press(Key.tab)
            keyboard.release(Key.tab)`
The code I want is complete.

Comment: I did not know the importance of the tab because it was my first Python. Tabs are pretty important. I did not care much about tabs on the web (simply visual convenience). It seems to be important in Python programming. Thank you!

Comment: @무공해 yes because blocks of code in Python do not depend on `{...}` like they do in many other languages. You separate blocks of code on whitespaces